# Is there a way to have nodejs code coverage when tests are written in python (pytest)?

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, code-coverage, pytest

I wrote Mocha tests in my previous project. The nice thing about it is the Istanbul code coverage tool. It is very useful and cool. 
Now I am using pytest for my current project. Some services are nodejs apps. Now my question is, is there a way I can have code coverage for nodejs app when I am using pytest?

Comment: Good question. Do you want to include the mocha tests in the `pytest` run or just include the coverage?

Comment: Thank you @hoefling. I just want code coverage. This is new product that I only have pytest, no Mocha.

Comment: The main challenge is writing a custom plugin for `coverage` that handles JS files since `coverage` naturally doesn't know or care about them; once you have that, rest is pretty simple. Let me extract the essential code from our custom plugins at work so I can provide you with a working example, I should be able to write an answer tomorrow evening then.

Comment: @hoefling, Thank you! Please no hurry!

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay! Take a look at the added answer, I guess it should help you to start with coding your own solution. Although the code in the github repo is runnable, it's by no means a complete and error-free implementation, so don't forget to check out the notes in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Combining coverage reports of `istanbul` and `coverage` tools has two major problems to solve:

1. Naturally, `coverage` does not know anything about javascript files, so we have to register them somehow in a coverage run - this will be done by implementing a custom plugin.
2. We have to convert `istanbul`s coverage report to a format `coverage` understands.

## Setup

Because the code snippet would be too large to put in in the answer directly, I have prepared a [git repository](https://github.com/hoefling/stackoverflow-52124836) you can reproduce the test run with (of course you can reuse the code however you want):

```
$ git clone https://github.com/hoefling/stackoverflow-52124836
$ cd stackoverflow-52124836/
$ yarn install
```

Generate istanbul coverage report first:

```
$ yarn test
  yarn run v1.9.4
  warning package.json: No license field
  $ istanbul cover _mocha js

  Array
    #length
      ✓ should be 0 when the array is empty
      ✓ should be 1 when the array has one element
      ✓ should be 2 when the array has two elements

  Array
    #indexOf()
      ✓ should return -1 when the value is not present


  4 passing (5ms)

=============================================================================
Writing coverage object [/private/tmp/stackoverflow-52124836/coverage/coverage.json]
Writing coverage reports at [/private/tmp/stackoverflow-52124836/coverage]
=============================================================================

=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : 100% ( 14/14 )
Branches     : 100% ( 0/0 )
Functions    : 100% ( 8/8 )
Lines        : 100% ( 14/14 )
================================================================================
```

Now run python tests with `pytest`:

```
$ python -m pytest -sv --cov=py --cov=js --cov-report=term-missing
=================================== test session starts ===================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.6.4, pytest-3.7.3, py-1.5.4, pluggy-0.7.1 --
 /Users/hoefling/.virtualenvs/stackoverflow/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /private/tmp/stackoverflow-52124836, inifile:
plugins: cov-2.5.1
collected 1 item

py/test_spam.py::test_spam PASSED

---------- coverage: platform darwin, python 3.6.4-final-0 -----------
Name                      Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
-------------------------------------------------------
js/array.length.spec.js      14      0   100%
js/array.spec.js              8      0   100%
py/test_spam.py               2      0   100%
-------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                        24      0   100%

================================ 1 passed in 0.56 seconds =================================
```

### `js`/`py` dirs

These are just some example test files to play with. To simplify the setup, `istanbul` collects the coverage over the test code.

### `mycov`

Contains the plugin for `coverage`. For in-depth info on how to write plugins for `coverage`, refer to [Plug-in classes](https://coverage.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_plugin.html); here I just explain the relevant spots:

```
class IstanbulPlugin(coverage.plugin.CoveragePlugin, coverage.plugin.FileTracer):

    def file_reporter(self, filename):
        return FileReporter(filename)

    def file_tracer(self, filename):
        return None

    def find_executable_files(self, src_dir):
        yield from (str(p) for p in pathlib.Path(src_dir).rglob('*.js')
                    if not any(d in p.parts for d in ('node_modules', 'coverage',)))
```

The plugin class does nothing besides searching for javascript files and registering them as executed ones in `coverage` run (`find_executable_files` method). It does not record code coverage at all! It also registers a simple file reporter impl for javascript files:

```
class FileReporter(coverage.plugin.FileReporter):

    def source(self):
        with open(self.filename) as fp:
            js = fp.read()
        return js

    def lines(self):
        return {i + 1 for i, line in enumerate(self.source().split(os.linesep)) if line.strip()}
```

The reporter returns the source code of javascript files as-is, executable lines are all code lines that are not empty.

---

#### Note 1:

This impl is not sufficient! For example, line and block comment lines will be counted as executable. You will need to adapt the `lines` method; best is to use some javascript code parser that extracts the info about the executable lines.

#### Note 2:

Both `istanbul` and `coverage` count lines from 1 and not from 0, thus the shift in line numbers.

---

Now you need to register the plugin via `coverage_init`:

```
# mycov/__init__.py

def coverage_init(reg, options):
    reg.add_file_tracer(IstanbulPlugin())
```

and add the custom plugin in `.coveragerc`:

```
[run]
plugins = mycov
```

## Append `istanbul` report to `coverage`

Now that `coverage` knows the javascript files are to be considered, we will merge the js coverage with the python one. The fixture `append_istanbul_coverage` in `conftest.py` is responsible for that.

```
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def append_istanbul_coverage(cov):
    yield

    with open('coverage/coverage.json') as fp:
        data = json.load(fp)
    converted = {'lines': {item['path']: line_numbers(item) for item in data.values()}}
    text = "!coverage.py: This is a private format, don't read it directly!" + json.dumps(converted)
    istanbul_cov = coverage.data.CoverageData()

    with io.StringIO(text) as fp:
        istanbul_cov.read_fileobj(fp)
    cov.data.update(istanbul_cov)
```

The fixture will be automatically executed once per test run, code after `yield` will be run when all tests are done. The [`cov` fixture](https://pytest-cov.readthedocs.io/en/latest/markers-fixtures.html#cov) is provided by `pytest-cov`; we use it to access the current `coverage` data object. First, we read the `istanbul` coverage; then convert it to a string that can be understood by `coverage` - this is just plain `json` with a special message prepended. After that, all that is left is to update the current `coverage` data are we're done!

Comment: Thank you so much.  I think I will need sometime to try out. My evening and weekend work again. If this can work, I can bring the pytest to a different level. It would be much useful for team. Down side is, boss will know how much are covered :D

Comment: i finally got time looking into this after a busy release I see you wrote test in nodejs. In my case, I use python request to talk to endpoints. I think i am asking something impossible. How could python request know what line of nodejs code it is accessing?  Next time I can use  mocha for the nodejs part and use pytest to deal with something else. then take your approach for a final report. Thank you! @hoefling

Comment: I guess you can do that either, you need to run your app server in coverage mode (presumably with `nyc` or similar tool), then run python tests against that started server instance. After the tests finish, append the generated `coverage.json` to the pytest cov report same way as I do that in the answer. I guess it's more a question of a correct configuration then.

Comment: I guess I didn't understand it is the app server that can run in coverage mode. This is good news.  I am moving to different team but I still need to maintain the pytest. I will have limited time but will try.